# Add a cache on the ad displayed

Tags: feature-request, advertising

It happened multiple times.

I was browsing the main page of SO and I clicked on a question, and while the request was being sent, my eyes glanced over the SE network question-type ad on the right. I had time to read the question and it was relevant to my interest (although unrelated to programming), but the page concerning the question I requested loaded.

I quickly pressed back to re-read the question and be able to follow the link, but once the page reloaded, it was displaying another question that was no longer relevant.

I can't believe I'm asking this concerning advertising, but I'd like to be able to press back and still have the same ad. Maybe use a 10 to 15 seconds cache on ads.

Comment: +1, this has happened to me a number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like this was implemented. I can now go back and I still see the same ad.

Comment: many (but not all) of the things you would find advertised would be on the network-wide hot list at http://stackexchange.com though you might  have to scroll down a bit.